# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON. how to solve this error

Tags: reactjs

```
  let getWeatherInfo = async ()=>{
  let response  =await fetch(`${API_KEY}?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}`);
  
  try {
    let jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the error here. Network errors, for example, will reach this block.
    console.log("Error while processing the JSON response:",error);
  }
```

Comment: its clear from the error that you are getting html as the api response, check you api response on the network tab in browser devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the response's ok field to see if it was successful before trying to parse it as JSON.

```
  let getWeatherInfo = async () => {
  let response = await fetch(`${API_KEY}?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}`);

  try {
    // Check if the response is okay
    if (response.ok) {
      // If response is okay, parse it as JSON
      let jsonResponse = await response.json();
      console.log(jsonResponse);
    } else {
      // If response not okay, log the status
      console.log("Response not okay. Status:", response.status);
      // Throw an error here if you want to handle it in a higher level
      // throw new Error('Response not okay');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle other network errors
    console.log("Error while processing the JSON response:", error);
  }
};
```